# How to get palette hexadecimal

Tags: java, android

I have a picture (url) and i want to have the pallete hexadecimal code.

So I did this with a library that i found in github that mixes picasso with pallete:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/289079-6.jpg").into(fotomenu_1,
            PicassoPalette.with("http://thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/289079-6.jpg", fotomenu_1)
                    .intoCallBack(new PicassoPalette.CallBack() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPaletteLoaded(Palette palette) { 

                        }
                    })
);
```

(library: https://github.com/florent37/PicassoPalette)

How do I get the colors in hexadecimal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The library gives you a palette from support library.
Take a look at these two lines: [1](https://github.com/florent37/PicassoPalette/blob/master/picassopalette/src/main/java/com/github/florent37/picassopalette/BitmapPalette.java#L25) and [2](https://github.com/florent37/PicassoPalette/blob/master/picassopalette/src/main/java/com/github/florent37/picassopalette/BitmapPalette.java#L6)

So now your problem is how to access the colors of palette. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) of it is good and it makes a lot of public method to return int color value. You can use any of those depends on your need.

Comment: I just added int color = palette.getLightMutedColor(0); but it always comes out 0 do you know why?

Comment: Yes, because it depends on your image. it dose not guarantee that all images have those named color.

Comment: I just want like the most used color... In that exemple its a shade of red, how can I have it? - Thanks